# Отметить файлы как  без изменений

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

Есть много файлов, которые из-за разных манипуляций помечены теперь как с изменениями.
Как исправить ситуацию? Пробовал `git reset --hard`, не помогло. Возможно дело в окончаниях строк, ругалось на них.  
Спасибо

Comment: git checkout имяфайла не пробовали? (только указывате нужные файлы, а то потеряете все).

Comment: git checkout -- имяфайла

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, стоит понять, [в чём же изменения](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

```
git diff имяфайла
git diff -w имяфайла
```

Попробуйте также сделать `git add .`. Если изменены окончания строк, то будут сообщения вроде этого:

> LF will be replaced by CRLF

(Используйте `git reset .`, чтобы отменить индексирование).

Если дело в окончаниях строк, подумайте, кто их сломал. Возможно, это был текстовый редактор или IDE. Обычно в них можно настроить, какие окончания строк использовать.

Настройте Git: [Как настроить autocrlf в git для различных систем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/406466/181472). После настройки проверьте ещё раз с `git diff` и `git status`.

Если `git reset --hard` не работает, то вряд ли сработает рекомендуемый `git checkout .`. Обе команды не будут переписывать файл, если с точки зрения Git файл не изменился (одинаков sha1). Может помочь следующее: удалите конфликтные файлы, после этого сделайте `git checkout .`.