# Как настроить autocrlf в git для различных систем?

Tags: git, git-config

Если я правильно понял, то в windows при `autocrlf = true` Git будет делать конвертацию `CRLF` -> `LF` после коммита, а `LF` -> `CRLF` при чекауте.

В моем рабочем процессе возможны случаи, когда исходные файлы сбрасываются вручную, минуя репозиторий, с рабочей директории репозитория первой машины Linux/Windows в рабочую директорию второй Windows-машины.

При этом в этих исходных файлах строки содержат `LF`-окончание, а в рабочей директории второй машины `CRLF`. Значит ли это, что придется вручную их конвертировать сторонним софтом к `CRLF` виду?

**Как правильно настроить `core.autocrlf` на обеих рабочих машинах, чтобы избежать ошибок при "ручном" переносе файлов?**

Предполагаю, что в Windows - `autocrlf = true`, а в Linux - `autocrlf = input` (чтобы предотвратить случай выше, только уже с `CRLF`).

Answer (score 10):

Я протестировал все варианты и вот, что вышло:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ core.autocrlf ║     false    ║     input    ║     true     ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║   git commit  ║ LF => LF     ║ LF => LF     ║ LF => CRLF   ║
║               ║ CR => CR     ║ CR => CR     ║ CR => CR     ║
║               ║ CRLF => CRLF ║ CRLF => LF   ║ CRLF => CRLF ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║  git checkout ║ LF => LF     ║ LF => LF     ║ LF => CRLF   ║
║               ║ CR => CR     ║ CR => CR     ║ CR => CR     ║
║               ║ CRLF => CRLF ║ CRLF => CRLF ║ CRLF => CRLF ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Считаю, что самый оптимальный вариант на всех системах `core.autocrlf = input`. При этом на всех ОС окончания строк `CRLF` при необходимости будут неявно преобразованы к `LF`, если уже есть `LF`, то так и останется.

Answer (score 5):

> Как правильно настроить core.autocrlf на обеих рабочих машинах, чтобы избежать ошибок при "ручном" переносе файлов?

я думаю, во всех операционных системах имеет смысл присвоить этому атрибуту как минимум значение `input`.

тогда при добавлении «ненормализованных» файлов (т.е., с разделителем строк *crlf*), будет выдаваться предупреждение, что файл в репозитории будет преобразован, а при последующем коммите файлы будут автоматически «нормализованы» (разделитель *crlf* будет заменён на *lf*).

а при выполнении команды *checkout* никаких преобразований делаться не будет — файлы в рабочей копии будут иметь те же разделители, что и в репозитории<sup>1</sup>.

возможно, в операционных системах, где по умолчанию разделителем служит не *lf*, а *crlf* (например, *ms/windows*), имеет смысл «пойти дальше», и присвоить атрибуту *core.autocrlf* значение `true` — чтобы **и** при команде *checkout* производилось преобразование *lf* → *crlf*. но это, вероятно, имеет смысл только в том случае, если используемая для просмотра/редактирования этих файлов программа отображает содержимое файлов некорректно (т.е., не делает перенос строки, встретив символ *lf*).

---

<sup>1</sup> — посмотреть, как именно хранится файл в репозитории, можно, например, с помощью команды `git cat-file -p хэш`. пример:

инициализируем репозиторий:

```
$ git init
```

добавляем в файл две строки и делаем коммит:

```
$ echo 1 > file; echo 2 >> file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m 1
[master (root-commit) 1373ad1] 1
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file
```

просматриваем содержимое коммита, указав его хэш (можно сокращённый):

```
$ git cat-file -p 1373ad1
tree d25d3b6082891168b6787cb20783bd332e5b8f74
...
```

просматриваем объект типа *tree*, добавленный этим коммитом:

```
$ git cat-file -p d25d3b6
100644 blob 1191247b6d9a206f6ba3d8ac79e26d041dd86941    file
```

просматриваем объект типа *blob*, содержащий тот самый файл:

```
$ git cat-file -p 1191247 | hexdump -C
00000000  31 0a 32 0a                                       |1.2.|
00000004
```

и видим, что сохранился он в репозитории с разделителем строк *lf*.