# Как поменять line endings в Visual Studio 2017 (русская версия)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Скачала Unity, пишу скрипт на C# в Microsoft Visual Studio, но возникает проблема inconsistent  line endings.

Везде пишут, что нужно зайти в Файл - Дополнительные параметры сохранения, но у меня нет такой опции. Есть только сохранить, сохранить как и сохранить все (в меню "Сохранить как" тоже нет никаких дополнительных опций).

Где же все-таки поменять line endings?

Answer (score 3):

Не путайте 2015 и 2017 студию. Вот у меня обе стоят: на 2015 такой пункт есть, а на 2017 его нет, [потеряли](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/21789/visual-studio-2017rc-lost-the-advance-save-menu.html). (В ней допустим потеряли также и настройки публикации asp.net mvc проекта, мне было неудобно)

Пока не поправят -- пользуйтесь хоткеем `File.AdvancedSaveOptions` (штатно на Ctrl+Alt+Z находится). Я этот хоткей запомнил очень хорошо: однажды пришлось пробежаться по всему проекту поправить кодировку и постоянно в меню кликать мышкой было долго и неудобно, быстрее и получилось через хоткей. Так и запомнил.

Что ещё:

- В 2015 студии этот пункт меню появляется только когда открыт файл и настройка применяется к одному конкретному выделенному файлу.
- Возможно, ваши файлы находятся в git и возможно, что вы используете не очень удобные параметры настройки git config core.autocrlf на компьютере (очень много тем на en so, а [на русском есть вот такая тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/406466/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-autocrlf-%d0%b2-git-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc/606605#606605))

Answer (score 2):

Дополнительные параметры сохранения перекочевали в кнопку "Сохранить". Выберите **File → Save as...** У кнопки **Save** вы увидите стрелку вниз, которая ведет к дополнительным параметрам сохранения (Save with Encoding...). В ней вы найдете нужные вам параметры.

---

[image: Дополнительные параметры]

[image: Line Ending]