# Graphviz + C# некорректно отображаются русские символы

Tags: c#, graphviz

Есть тестовая программа на C# VS 2017 которая рисует граф с помощью GraphViz.
Не удается подружить ее с русскими символами, отображается абракадабра.
Подскажите, как с русскими буквами научить работать GraphViz, может кто сталкивался уже?

Основной код и текст DOT:

```
namespace GraphVizTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String GrapgVizString = @"digraph g 
            {ratio = fill;
            node[style = filled]
            label = ""Andre van Dun "";
            InitialInitial->AwaitingAnalysis[color=""0.650 0.700 0.700""] [label =<<B>manual+</B>>];
            subgraph cluster0 
            {label = ""Initial "";
            GroomingGrooming->GroomingFinished[label =""manual""];
            GroomingFinished[color=""0.449 0.447 1.000""]Groomingnever[color=""0.000 1.000 1.000""]
            }
            AwaitingAnalysis[color=""0.590 0.273 1.000""]
            AwaitingAnalysis->AwaitingDevelopment[color=""0.650 0.700 0.700""][label =""manual""];
            AwaitingDevelopment[color=""0.590 0.273 1.000""]
            AwaitingDevelopment->InDevelopment[color=""0.650 0.700 0.700""] [label =""**МОЙ ТЕКСТ**""];
            AwaitingDevelopment->AwaitingDelivery[color=""0.650 0.700 0.700""] [label =""manual""];
            InDevelopment[color=""0.590 0.273 1.000""]
            InDevelopment->AwaitingDelivery[color=""0.650 0.700 0.700""] [label =""manual""];
            AwaitingDelivery[color=""0.449 0.447 1.000""]}";

            ///Option 1
            //pictureBox1.Image = Examples.Run(GrapgVizString);
            ///Option 2
            pictureBox1.Image = Examples.Graphviz.RenderImage(GrapgVizString, "jpg");
            this.Size = pictureBox1.Image.Size;

        }
    }
}
```

Код класса:

```
namespace GraphVizTest
{
    public static class Examples
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// OPTION 1
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dot"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Image Run(string dot)
        {
            string executable = @".\external\dot.exe";
            string output = @".\external\tempgraph";
            File.WriteAllText(output, dot);

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            // Stop the process from opening a new window
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            // Setup executable and parameters
            process.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"{0} -Tjpg -O -Tps:cairo", output);

            // Go
            process.Start();
            // and wait dot.exe to complete and exit
            process.WaitForExit();
            Image image;
            using (Stream bmpStream = System.IO.File.Open(output + ".jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(bmpStream);

            }
            File.Delete(output);
            File.Delete(output + ".jpg");
            return image;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// OPTION 2
        /// </summary>
        public static class Graphviz
        {
            public const string LIB_GVC = @".\external\gvc.dll";
            public const string LIB_GRAPH = @".\external\cgraph.dll";
            public const int SUCCESS = 0;

            /// 
            /// Creates a new Graphviz context.
            /// 

            [DllImport(LIB_GVC, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern IntPtr gvContext();

            /// 
            /// Releases a context's resources.
            /// 
            [DllImport(LIB_GVC, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern int gvFreeContext(IntPtr gvc);

            /// 
            /// Reads a graph from a string.
            /// 
            [DllImport(LIB_GRAPH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern IntPtr agmemread(string data);


            /// 
            /// Releases the resources used by a graph.
            /// 
            [DllImport(LIB_GRAPH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern void agclose(IntPtr g);

            /// 
            /// Applies a layout to a graph using the given engine.
            /// 
            [DllImport(LIB_GVC, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern int gvLayout(IntPtr gvc, IntPtr g, string engine);


            /// 
            /// Releases the resources used by a layout.
            /// 
            [DllImport(LIB_GVC, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern int gvFreeLayout(IntPtr gvc, IntPtr g);

            /// 
            /// Renders a graph to a file.
            /// 
            [DllImport(LIB_GVC, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern int gvRenderFilename(IntPtr gvc, IntPtr g,
                  string format, string fileName);

            /// 
            /// Renders a graph in memory.
            /// 
            [DllImport(LIB_GVC, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern int gvRenderData(IntPtr gvc, IntPtr g,
                  string format, out IntPtr result, out int length);

            /// 
            /// Release render resources.
            /// 
            [DllImport(LIB_GVC, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern int gvFreeRenderData(IntPtr result);


            public static Image RenderImage(string source, string format)
            {
                // Create a Graphviz context
                IntPtr gvc = gvContext();
                if (gvc == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Exception("Failed to create Graphviz context.");

                // Load the DOT data into a graph
                IntPtr g = agmemread(source);
                if (g == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Exception("Failed to create graph from source. Check for syntax errors.");

                // Apply a layout
                if (gvLayout(gvc, g, "dot") != SUCCESS)
                    throw new Exception("Layout failed.");

                IntPtr result;
                int length;

                // Render the graph
                if (gvRenderData(gvc, g, format, out result, out length) != SUCCESS)
                    throw new Exception("Render failed.");

                // Create an array to hold the rendered graph
                byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

                // Copy the image from the IntPtr
                Marshal.Copy(result, bytes, 0, length);

                // Free up the resources
                gvFreeRenderData(result);
                gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
                agclose(g);
                gvFreeContext(gvc);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    return Image.FromStream(stream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите, а какая [кодировка файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686620/213987) в котором содержится `label =""**МОЙ ТЕКСТ**""`?

Comment: Вот тут есть граф: https://habr.com/post/147843/ и в соответствии с ним, ищите что за кодировку вы ему пытаетесь подсунуть вместо родной. Рекомендую пробовать слать туда хотябы UTF8, а не вашу windows-кодировку

Comment: В текст файла модуля в кодировке: Юникод(UTF-8,с сигнатурой, код. страница 65001).

Comment: А переменная типа System.String в которой храниться текст описания графа в кодировке UTF-16.

Comment: если рисовать тестовый граф в самой программе символы будут нормально отображаться?

Comment: @Foggy Finder Да, в самой программе все ок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Решил так: конвектирую текст описания графа из 1251 в utf-8 перед загрузкой в компоненту(пример кода ниже). 
Спасибо @test123 за наводку.

```
public byte[] RenderImage(string source, string format)
                           {
                                // Create a Graphviz context
                                IntPtr gvc = gvContext();
                                if (gvc == IntPtr.Zero)
                                    throw new Exception("Failed to create Graphviz context.");

                                //+upd преобразуем в utf-8, иначе GraphViz отображает русские символы, как кракозябры 
                                Encoding utf8 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                                Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
                                byte[] utf8Bytes = win1251.GetBytes(source);
                                byte[] win1251Bytes = Encoding.Convert(win1251, utf8, utf8Bytes);
                                source = win1251.GetString(win1251Bytes);
                                //-upd
         // Load the DOT data into a graph
                    IntPtr g = agmemread(source);
                    if (g == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new Exception("Failed to create graph from source. Check for syntax errors.");
                ...
                }
```