# Register и Log in, в правом верхнем углу проекта ASP.NET Core MVC, на русском языке?

Tags: c#, html

Как сделать так что бы надпись Register и Log in, в правом верхнем углу проекта ASP.NET Core MVC, была на русском языке? Вместо русского там вопросы в ромбах. UTF-8 в проекте есть.

Comment: [сохранить файл в utf-8](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2017) + указать в html кодировку utf-8

Comment: Вообще, хотя бы версию студии указали... Возможно пригодится [эта инструкция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/686576/213987). И ещё не забудьте, что у вас в layout страницы указывается кодировка.