# Перевод строки и линтеры

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, visual-studio-code, best-practice

Я слышал, что в 2019 году не модно собирать javascript-проекты без линтера, но вот я такой мамонт, только начинаю осваивать.

И что-то у меня не стыкуется в голове одно с другим. Основная ОС у меня - windows, переводы строки CRLF (допустим, в той же vscode). Гит поставленный по умолчанию предлагает core.autocrlf = true (т.е. файлы хранятся в CRLF на диске, а при уходе в репозиторий преобразуются в LF) - тынц [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/406466/213987) на ru so, en so и по всему интернету рекомендуют именно эту настройку.

А как доходит дело до установки vue, то при vue init webpack файлы на диске оказываются все поголовно в LF - и это в принципе мне было незаметно, пока я не включил линтер, который тут же ругнулся множеством ошибок [Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style)

```
http://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style  Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'
  src\router\index.js:15:4
  });
```

И сиди жми Shift + Alt + F на всех тронутых файлах. А потом при создании нового файла не забудь поменять формат строк. А если сделал git rebase/reset, чтобы причесать коммиты - всё, начинай сначала.

<s>Почему я не вижу вообще никаких следов этих обсуждений, как будто я первый продираюсь? Толи все поголовно врут, что настроили линтер ("и вы говорите"), толи настройка свелась к отключению надоедливых правил (тогда это не настройка, а профанация), толи все промолчали что и как настроили, так как это всем очевидно.</s>

Но мне как-то не очень. Давайте попробую сформулировать вопрос. В какую сторону двигаться:

- толи мода постепенно смещается в сторону "да, сидим под виндой, но используем LF"
- толи двигаемся в сторону "на винде сидим на CRLF, на маках на LF"

Я допустим, могу понять первый (LF) вариант так. Для репозиториев указываем core.autocrlf = false, в vscode ставим files.eol = \n и работаем на win как на lin. Настройка конечно требуется, но разовая - зато дальше правила линтера одинаковые на всех машинах (lf), сборочных и тестовых серверах.

А второй (CRLF) вариант вроде как кажется более родным для win (настраивать git и vscode не требуется), но я в упор не понимаю, как тогда пользуются одним и тем же .eslintrc.js на разных машинах и на какую настройку равняться на сборочном сервере. Как-то методологически непонятно, есть ли смысл в проверке исходников на общие правила, если проверяются разные исходники разными калибрами? Ну разве что тупо [отключить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37826625/5752652), если у всех в команде win.

Вроде как уже пора выбрать какое-то одно направление и идти дожимать оставшиеся неясными вопросы, но непонятно куда идти. Что сейчас в этом вопросе считается бест практис?

Comment: что-то похожее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1012434/178576

Answer (score 1):

В общем, я подумал и решил пойти по пути LF:

1. В файле .git\config добавил строки:

   [core]
   autocrlf = false
2. В файле .vscode\settings.json  добавил настройку

   "files.eol": "\n",

И на этом вроде всё. Один проект погоняю, набью шишки и может быть со временем поменяю своё мнение — что не надо было в эту сторону идти.